# How to avoid ListTile title realign when add leading/trailing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to maintain a centered title (text) on `ListTile` even if I'm using a trailing icon.
I've tried to use an expanded but it does not work.

[image: ListTile not centered text]
I need "Italiano" text centered like "Inglese"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@E.Benedos, no matter how you center the text, it will try to center it in the available space. When you remove the trailing icon from one of the ListTiles, it will try to use that empty space. One way i can think of is to fill the space with empty container with same width as the icon. If you're using built-in `Icons.check` with default size then the default size is 24.0 so you can use a Container with width 24.0 as below (not sure how you're handling the selection, the code below is just an example),

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool itSelected = false;
  bool engSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Center(child: Text('Italiano')),
                        trailing: itSelected ? Icon(Icons.check) : Container(width: 24.0),
                        onTap: () {
                          itSelected = true;
                          engSelected = false;
                          setState(() {});
                        },

                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Center(child: Text('Inglese')),
                        trailing: engSelected ? Icon(Icons.check) : Container(width: 24.0),
                        onTap: () {
                          engSelected = true;
                          itSelected = false;
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      )
                    ])
                  )
            )
            ));
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

**EDIT:** To horizontally center (center of the screen) the title along with icon, you can use combination of Stack, Positioned and Inkwell and try something like this (i don't think there is a better way to achieve that with ListTile),

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool itSelected = false;
  bool engSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 50.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Stack(
                                  children:<Widget>[
                                    Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Italiano', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),)),
                                    itSelected ? Positioned(top: 12.0, right: 10.0, child: Icon(Icons.check)) : Container(),
                                  ])
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            itSelected = true;
                            engSelected = false;
                            setState(() {});
                          },

                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 50.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Stack(
                                  children:<Widget>[
                                    Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Inglese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),)),
                                    engSelected ? Positioned(top: 12.0, right: 10.0, child: Icon(Icons.check)) : Container(),
                                  ])
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            itSelected = false;
                            engSelected = true;
                            setState(() {});
                          },

                        )
                    ])
                  )
            )
            ));
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Pro thank you to your explanation and your time. Yes at the moment I'm handling the selection. Your solution can be a valid patch, but my final purpose is to maintain the text aligned with the center of the screen like if there is no icon set

Comment: Nice solution! This is perfectly what I was looking for